# Twilio Inbound Text Message to Outbound Voice Call

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-functions

I want Twilio to initiate an outbound call to my mobile phone when anyone sends a text message to my Twilio number.

I would prefer to do this with a TwiML Bin or Twilio Function or something hosted by Twilio so I do not have to run my own web server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some [Functions help documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/runtime/programmable-voice#create-a-new-function) that got me moving in the right direction.

I've got a TwiML Bin "SMS to Voice TwiML Bin":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say loop="3">{{Body}}</Say>
</Response>
```

And a Function "SMS to Voice Function" that uses that TwiML:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const client = context.getTwilioClient()
  client.calls.create({
    to:   '+...', 
    from: '+...', 
    url:  'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/...?Body=' + encodeURIComponent(event.Body) }, // SMS to Voice TwiML Bin
    function(err, res) {
      callback(err, "OK")
    })
};
```

And in the Twilio console, for my Twilio number, under Messaging, I have my A MESSAGE COMES IN set to "Function" and "SMS to Voice Function".

This works. If the Twilio number receives a text, then Twilio calls my mobile phone number and speaks the original text message.

Comment: Sounds like you've nailed it. Let me know (or ask another question tagged Twilio) if you need any more guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing, this is a response that is coming from an inbound SMS message.

The problem is that you need to initiate an actual phone call. The SMS message is not in a call so it cannot dial anything.

Check out the documentation for [Making Calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls) for how you can start a call. You will likely need the SMS to hit a function (Twilio function or your own code) that can then make the Twilio REST call to start a new call.